# Canonical form of module in a real quadratic field

Tags: number-theory, modules, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, lattice-orders

Consider a real quadratic field K. Let M be a complete Z-module in K.

I would like to see a proof that it can be multiplied by a totally positive number $x$ so that
$$xM=\mathbb{Z} + w\mathbb{Z}$$
where $w \in K$ is such that
$$0<\bar{w}<1<w.$$

Moreover, is there a specific method to find such a $w$?

Comment: What is a complete $\Bbb{Z}$-module, do you mean a lattice?

Comment: @reuns Yes, a rank 2 lattice here

Comment: Does this question arise from van der Geer's *Hilbert Modular Surfaces*? I think he describes how to do this in section II.5 in terms of the reduction theory for binary quadratic forms.